# get data from dynamically bounded text field by ng-repeat in controller function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have been trying to get the values in controller from the input text fields which are generated via ng-repeat, but was not able to do so.
here is my code snippet

```
<div ng-controller= "educationCtrl"  ng-init="showEducation()">
  <div ng-repeat="value in gg" for="{{value}}">
    <p>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>University Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model ="uname" value=""  placeholder=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Degree </td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model ="degname" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Year of Joining</td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model ="yoj" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Year of leaving</td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model ="yol" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Grades</td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model ="grades" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button type="submit" data-ng-click = "educationUpdate()" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:30px" >update</span></button></td>
          <td><button type="submit" data-ng-click= "toggle()" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:30px" >Cancel</span></button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </p>
  </div>
```

```
function educationCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
  $scope.educationUpdate = function() {
    alert("uname +"$scope.uname+ "degname :" +$scope.degname);
  };
}
```

but was not able to do so...

Answer (score 0):

You are making iteration, so the ng-model must not be the same for each set of inputs. Try adding a value to your "value" child of "gg":

```
 <tr><td>University Name</td><td><input type="text" ng-model ="value.uname"
 value=""  placeholder=""/></td></tr>
```

Then add the $index value in your ng-submit function :

```
<tr><td><button type="submit" data-ng-click = "educationUpdate($index)" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:30px" >update</span></button></td>
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.educationUpdate = function(idx) {
    alert("uname +"$scope.bb[idx].uname+ "degname :" +$scope.bb[idx].degname);
};
```

Hope this helps.

Little thing, should be better for you to use form validation system angular, using ng-submit instead of ng-click:

```
<form name="" ng-submit="educationUpdate($index)">...code...</form>
```

More details [on Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit)